# Why is there only ten increments for alpha in css "rgba();"?

Tags: css, hex, type-conversion, decimal

From what I understand is that the minimum values for this CSS command is:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);          /equivalent hex rgba #0000
```

and the maximum values

```
rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);    /equivalent hex rgba #FFFF
```

Now, say we look at the `r`: its decimal is `255`, and its hex is `#F`, which is easily expanded/converted to `#FF`.

```
#FF = 255
```

On the computer side, hex reads `0 to F` (Base 16). On the human side, the decimal input reads `0.0 to 1.0` (Base 10). Essentially, there is only 10 acceptable inputs out of a possible 16.

So my question, what happens with the other 6 unobtainable input values? How does the alpha channel translate?

Comment: alpha channel only change opacity , I do not believe it effects the color itself that you use rgba() or hsla()

Comment: test this with a background http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EIFkg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for finer grained opacity settings you may use Alpha values with more than one decimal place. For example RGBA(255,255,255,0.05) will yield the expected results as a very light tint of White.
The answer was given here: [Html rgba color opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409115/html-rgba-color-opacity)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the rgba notation in CSS, remember that the last digit is used for opacity. So it's value it's not counted in the color rgb.

`rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);`   The first 3 digits are for the rgb color value and the fourth digit 1 is for **opacity** and it could be also decimal like 0.5 for example.

Remember that IE8 does not support this notation.

http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba